# Is it possible in Play 2.1 to convert a JsValue to a case class instance if you only know the name of the case class at the runtime?

Tags: scala, reflection, playframework, playframework-2.1, scala-2.10

I'm building a JSON RPC in Play 2.1. In order to call the proper methods the RPC dispatcher is using reflection to create and call a class method instance by name.

Right now a RPC method looks like this:

```
  def create(obj: JsValue) = {
    val menu: Menu = Json.fromJson[Menu](obj).get
    collection.insert(menu).map( r => toDirectResult(r))
  }

  def createCustom(obj: JsValue) = {
    val menu: Menu = Json.fromJson(obj)(Menu.customFormat).get
    collection.insert(menu).map( r => toDirectResult(r))
  }
```

What I would like to do is to be able to define the RPC methods like this:

```
  def create(menu: Menu) = {
    collection.insert(menu).map( r => toDirectResult(r))
  }
```

The problem is that the RPC dispatcher only knows at the runtime that is has to call the method named "create" on the class named "Menus" and it has the value of the argument to pass to the method as a JsValue. Through reflection I can find out the number of arguments and their types for the RPC method. When the argument type is a case class, how do I transform the JsValue into a case class instance using the implicit Formatter (or Reader) defined in the companion object of the case class?

For the createCustom method I realize that there is no "magic" solution, but since I started learning Scala I discovered that few things are truly impossible with this programming language. Would it be possible to use an annotation or something similar to specify a Formatter that is not implicit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further careful consideration I've decided that reflection is really no the right solution for my problem. It lacks type safety and proper error reporting at compile time, it is harder to debug and has an impact on the performance as well. And I actually have all the information I need to generate the code at build time.

Unfortunately I cannot use the Play router because for the JSON RPC dispatcher the routing depends on the request body, which is not available during the Play routing. But in essence the RPC dispatcher is doing the same thing as the Play router. So for the moment I'm just going to manually code my RPC routes and then the problem in the question is solved. In the future I'm planning to write a SBT plugin that will automatically generate the dispatcher code, similar to the Play router.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a PathBinder...this should help out http://www.richard-foy.fr/blog/2012/04/09/how-to-implement-a-custom-pathbindable-with-play-2/

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work. The RPC methods are not actions inside a controller to be able to map them with routes. What I'm doing is an implementation of [ExtDirect](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/extdirect) so the client-side calls just one URL, everything else is posted as JSON.